# qualify statement with case statements in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, row-number

I am trying to execute below query which has got a lot of case statements in qualify clause.

```
insert into tab2 b
select  
      a.id,a.name
    from tab1 a
where a.country='US'
qualify(
       row_number() over(partition by a.university_id 
       order by 
       case when a.student_in_computerscience_fl='Y' then 1 else 0 end,
       case when a.student_in_chemistry_fl='Y' then 1 else 0 end,
       case when a.student_in_electronics_fl='Y' or a.student_in_physics_fl='Y' then 1 else 0 end,                 )=1)
```

Will the presence of a qualify with lot of case statements generate performance issues?

or do i have to use a temp table where i will store the rank(rk) as an additional field?
like

```
insert into tmptab
select  
      a.id,a.name,
     row_number() over(partition by a.university_id 
       order by 
       case when a.student_in_computerscience_fl='Y' then 1 else 0 end,
       case when a.student_in_chemistry_fl='Y' then 1 else 0 end,
       case when a.student_in_electronics_fl='Y' or a.student_in_physics_fl='Y' then 1 else 0 end                 ) as rk
    from tab1 a
where a.country='US'
```

and then to insert the final target table from above mentioned temporary table.

```
issert into tab2
(name,id)
select name,id from tmptab where rk=1
```

Kindly share your opinion.

Comment: Without facts it's a guess, but inserts are not "free" and you are still performing the same logic to make that first temp table; so I don't see the point, just use qualify. BUT; only though testing would you get a real answer and I may be on the losing team.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution (`QUALIFY`) should definitely be faster than the second (materialize rank). The expensive operation there is ranking (`ROW_NUMBER`) and you are going to do that in both cases.
What you will avoid doing by using the first solution is unnecessary data redistribution on your tmptab's primary index, sorting on RowKey (that will unnecessarily occure - unless you are writing to NoPI table) and then writing and reading the data from tmptab.
You can look at the `QUALIFY` clause simply a `WHERE` condition on a result of analytical function (`ROW_NUMBER`).